# list python package dependencies without loading them?

Tags: python, dependencies, packaging

Say that python package A requires B, C and D;
is there a way to list A → B C D without loading them ?
`Requires` in the metadata (`yolk -M A`) are often incomplete, grr.
One can download A.tar / A.egg, then look through A/setup.py,
but some of those are pretty gory.

(I'd have thought that getting at least first-level dependencies could be mechanized;
even a 98 % solution would be better than avalanching downloads.)

A related question:
[pip-upgrade-package-without-upgrading-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861183/pip-upgrade-package-without-upgrading-dependencies)

Answer (score 31):

[Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/)

```
sfood -fuq package.py | sfood-target-files
```

will list the dependencies.

```
`-f` tells sfood to follow dependencies recursively
`-u` tells sfood to ignore unused imports
`-q` tells sfood to be quiet about debugging information
```

To filter out modules from the standard library, you could use

```
sfood -fuq package.py | sfood-filter-stdlib | sfood-target-files
```

As you've already noted, if there are other directories you'd like ignored, you can also use the `sfood -I` flag.

Comment: looks reasonable, +1.  sfoodxx -I /Library/...python2.6 (mac) doesn't filter out standard imports sys, os.path etc. ?

Comment: @Denis: Use `sfood-filter-stdlib` to remove entries from the Python standard library. I'll edit my answer to include this...

Comment: sfood-filter-stdlib has '/usr/lib/python' hardwired in,
and doesn't work for sfood-imports.
Am asking the author ...
Bytheway Kevin Teague, "I want a pony" http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/msg/5407cdb400157259
is an outstanding overview of packaging methods in 2008.)

Comment: sfood-target-files is not available on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @Konstantin: That's odd. [It is in Ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sfood-target-files) and [also in 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sfood-target-files). You might try the [installation instructions per the documentation](http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html#installation) or upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Konstantin: `sfood-target-files` is in the distribution (at least for 14.04), as unutbu says; however, it is not linked to /usr/bin. It is in /usr/share/snakefood.  Same for `sfood-filter-stdlib`.  All tools mentioned in the [docs](http://furius.ca/snakefood/#tools-included) are linked in /usr/bin (by default install).

Answer (score 13):

[modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html) from the standard lib

> New in version 2.3.
>
> This module provides a ModuleFinder
>   class that can be used to determine
>   the set of modules imported by a
>   script. modulefinder.py can also be
>   run as a script, giving the filename
>   of a Python script as its argument,
>   after which a report of the imported
>   modules will be printed.

I am not sure if it complies with your requierement about not loading the modules. [From here](http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html):

> modulefinder use bytecode inspection
>   to find dependencies, and therefore is
>   free from any side-effects that may be
>   caused by importing the modules being
>   studied.

Other hints about the use of pylint or Gui2exe [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/674303-tool-finding-external-dependencies)

Comment: modulefinder does work but it will show a lot of useless stuff and indirect dependencies (dependencies that MAY be used by your dependencies, but actually are not). You can find an example script I did using modulefinder here: https://gist.github.com/lrq3000/6175634  And an alternative script using an AST parsing approach here (and which works way better for me): https://gist.github.com/lrq3000/6175522

Answer (score 6):

If by package you mean a pip installed package (and not a directory with an __init__.py), then you can use the Python package called pip. For example:

```
def get_all_package_dependencies():
    """Return dictionary of installed packages to list of package dependencies."""
    return {
        dist.key: [r.key for r in dist.requires()]
        for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions()
    }
```

Comment: I see a package on the web and want to know its deps.  There's `pip install --no-deps`, then dig around ... or are there newer pip commands to list-deps ?  (Requirements files are most often just not there.)

Comment: and pprint can be used to pretty print the output produced by above snippet

Comment: `get_installed_distributions` is now [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923671/are-there-any-function-replacement-for-pip-get-installed-distributions-in-pip).