# Identifying the dependency relationship for python packages installed with pip

Tags: python, pip

When I do a pip freeze I see large number of Python packages that I didn't explicitly install, e.g.

```
$ pip freeze
Cheetah==2.4.3
GnuPGInterface==0.3.2
Landscape-Client==11.01
M2Crypto==0.20.1
PAM==0.4.2
PIL==1.1.7
PyYAML==3.09
Twisted-Core==10.2.0
Twisted-Web==10.2.0
(etc.)
```

Is there a way for me to determine why pip installed these particular dependent packages?  In other words, how do I determine the parent package that had these packages as dependencies?

For example, I might want to use Twisted and I don't want to depend on a package until I know more about not accidentally uninstalling it or upgrading it.

Comment: Besides the `pipdeptree`, you might want to also try `johnnydep` and `pipgrip`.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

You could try [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) which displays dependencies as a tree structure e.g.:

```
$ pipdeptree
Lookupy==0.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
argparse==1.2.1
psycopg2==2.5.2
Flask-Script==0.6.6
  - Flask [installed: 0.10.1]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.7, installed: 0.9.4]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.4, installed: 2.7.2]
      - MarkupSafe [installed: 0.18]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.21, installed: 0.23]
alembic==0.6.2
  - SQLAlchemy [required: >=0.7.3, installed: 0.9.1]
  - Mako [installed: 0.9.1]
    - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.9.2, installed: 0.18]
ipython==2.0.0
slugify==0.0.1
redis==2.9.1
```

To get it run:

```
pip install pipdeptree
```

**EDIT:** as noted by @Esteban in the comments you can also list the tree in reverse with `-r` or for a single package with `-p <package_name>` so to find what installed Werkzeug you could run:

```bash
$ pipdeptree -r -p Werkzeug
Werkzeug==0.11.15
  - Flask==0.12 [requires: Werkzeug>=0.7]
```

Comment: I believe to fully answer @mark 's question you would need to run:
`pipdeptree -r` 

"Shows the dependency tree in the reverse fashion ie. the sub-dependencies are listed with the list of packages that need them under them."

Comment: How can you view the reverse tree for all PyPi packages, not only the locally installed packages?

Comment: `pipdeptree` is great. Unfortunately it does not appear to take into account dependencies for packages installed by conda: e.g. in a conda env where `matplotlib` and `numpy` were installed using pip, but `scipy` was installed using conda, `scipy` shows up in the pipdeptree as having no depencies and no dependents (also `pip show scipy` shows no requirements).

Comment: @Dennis I've not tried it but this might work for conda https://github.com/rvalieris/conda-tree

Comment: I use `pipdeptree -l -f` instead of just `pip freeze` and it's a pleasure to visually see the dependencies directly in the requirements file.

Comment: To use this in a virtual environment, you need to do `python -m pipdeptree` otherwise (even when the executable is installed to the virtualenv) it only lists the system dependencies.

Comment: pipdeptree is great, but it only works if the package is already installed.

Answer (score 129):

The `pip show` command will show what packages are required for the specified package (note that the specified package must already be installed):

```
$ pip show specloud

Package: specloud
Version: 0.4.4
Requires:
nose
figleaf
pinocchio
```

`pip show` was introduced in pip version 1.4rc5

Comment: `pip show` was introduced in version 1.4rc5, and is present in the (current as of writing) 1.4.1

Comment: This doesn't answer my question exactly, because it shows the children (dependencies) for a specific package, instead of the parents.  But it's easy enough to throw something together to check the dependencies of each package, using this command.  So, for example, I could determine which installed package required PyYAML.

Comment: As per my previous comment, this shell command dumps out all of the dependencies for each of my installed packages: $ pip freeze | grep -v "\-e" | sed s/\=\=.*// | awk 'system("pip show "  $1)'

Comment: An updated version of the script from my previous comment is `pip freeze | grep -v "\-e" | sed s/\=\=.*// | awk 'system("pip show " $1)' | grep -E '^(Name:|Requires:)' | sed s/Name:/\\\nName:/`  -- but it seems that pipdeptree is now a better solution.

Comment: As of pip 22.0.3 (and possibly earlier), `pip show` shows both other packages which require the package and other packages which are required by the package

Answer (score 27):

As I recently said on a [hn thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5431747), I'll recommend the following:

Have a commented `requirements.txt` file with your main dependencies:

```
## this is needed for whatever reason
package1
```

Install your dependencies: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
Now you get the full list of your dependencies with `pip freeze -r requirements.txt`:

```
## this is needed for whatever reason
package1==1.2.3

## The following requirements were added by pip --freeze:
package1-dependency1==1.2.3
package1-dependency1==1.2.3
```

This allows you to keep your file structure with comments, nicely separating your dependencies from the dependencies of your dependencies. This way you'll have a much nicer time the day you need to remove one of them :)

Note the following:

- You can have a clean `requirements.raw` with version control to rebuild your full `requirements.txt`.
- Beware of git urls being replaced by egg names in the process.
- The dependencies of your dependencies are still alphabetically sorted so you don't directly know which one was required by which package but at this point you don't really need it.
- Use `pip install --no-install <package_name>` to list specific requirements.
- Use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/) if you don't.

Comment: I just don't understand why this ``pip freeze -r requirements.txt`` is not widely used. Very useful for maintaining the dependencies and sub dependencies.

Comment: minor note: `pip install` no longer supports `--no-install`.

Answer (score 11):

The following command will show requirements of all installed packages:

```sh
pip3 freeze | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d '=' -f1 | xargs pip3 show
```

Comment: Super neat solution without additional pip dependencies. Just like it!

Answer (score 8):

You may also use a one line command which pipes the packages in requirements to pip show.

```
cut -d'=' -f1 requirements.txt | xargs pip show
```

Comment: Generally you can't as the format of requirements.txt is more complex than `<package_name>==<package_version>`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all `pip freeze` displays all currently installed packages Python, not necessarily using PIP.

Secondly Python packages do contain the information about dependent packages as well as [required versions](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-package). You can see the dependencies of particular pkg using the methods [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875232/list-python-package-dependencies-without-loading-them). When you're upgrading a package the installer script like PIP will handle the upgrade of dependencies for you.

To solve updating of packages i recommend using [PIP requirements files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html). You can define what packages and versions you need, and install them at once using pip install.

Answer (score 3):

**(workaround, not true answer)**

Had the same problem, with lxml not installing and me wanting to know who needed lxml.  **Not who lxml needed**.  Ended up bypassing the issue by.

1. noting where my site packages were being put.
2. go there and recursive grep for the import (the last grep's --invert-match serves to remove lxml's own files from consideration).

Yes, not an answer as to how to use pip to do it, but I didn't get any success out of the suggestions here, for whatever reason.

```
 site-packages me$ egrep -i --include=*.py  -r -n lxml . | grep import | grep --invert-match /lxml/
```

Answer (score 2):

## With GraphVis  <sup><sub><sub><sup>as seen on tv</sup></sub></sub></sup>

If you like graphs you can use `graphviz` ([Documentation](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html))

```bash
pip install graphviz
```

Then do something like this:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import graphviz
import pkg_resources

GRAPH_NAME = "pipdeps"

def init_grph():
    grph = graphviz.Digraph(GRAPH_NAME,
                     node_attr={'color': 'lightblue2', 'style': 'filled'})

    # This does not seem to be interpreted on websites I tested
    grph.attr(engine='neato')

    return grph

def add_pip_dependencies_to_graph(grph):
    l_packages = [p for p in pkg_resources.working_set]

    for package in l_packages:
        name = package.key
        for dep in package.requires():
            grph.edge(dep.key, name)

def main():
    grph = init_grph()
    add_pip_dependencies_to_graph(grph)

    print(grph.source)
    # grph.view()

main()
```

This prints a dotgraph/digraph/graphviz (idk ‍♀️)

You can view it for example in an online graphviz visualiser (e.g. https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline)

Alternatively if you have a graphic interface () you can use `grph.view()`

[image: screenshot of example graphical result]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick script to solve this problem. The following script will display the parent (dependant) package(s) for any given package. This way you can be sure it is safe to upgrade or install any particular package. It can be used as follows: `dependants.py PACKAGENAME`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Find dependants of a Python package"""

import logging
import pkg_resources  # tested with Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.10
import sys

__program__ = 'dependants.py'


def get_dependants(target_name):
    for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
        for requirement_package in package.requires():
            requirement_name = requirement_package.key
            if requirement_name == target_name:
                yield package.project_name


# configure logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

try:
    target_name = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    logging.error('missing package name')
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    pkg_resources.get_distribution(target_name)
except pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:
    logging.error("'%s' is not a valid package", target_name)
    sys.exit(1)

print(list(get_dependants(target_name)))
```

Comment: This no longer works because the `get_installed_distributions()` method is no longer available. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243

Comment: @PhilGyford It's still working for me with Python 3.12, although with a deprecation warning

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

#### #1

The first will output all top-level packages, excluding sub packages. Note that [this will also **exclude** for example requests, even if you want to have it explicitly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73669713/14348748) and **include** dependencies not explicit installed via pip (e.g. pip itself or setuptools which are needed by pip). Side note: these implicit dependencies can be also listed with `pip freeze` when used with the option `--all`. If you want to omit these *extra* dependencies one might exclude them with the `--exclude` option.

```bash
pip3 list --not-required --format freeze --exclude pip --exclude setuptools
```

#### #2

The second option is to print the packages based on the existing `requirements.txt` file.

```bash
pip3 freeze -r requirements.txt
```

This will generate a file in the format:

```
existing-package==1.0.0
## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:
dependency-package==1.0.0
```

You can remove all the additionally added packages [by using sed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284775):

```bash
pip3 freeze -r requirements.txt \
    | sed -n '/^## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:$/q;p'
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that both outputs from `pip freeze --all` and `pip list --format=freeze` are identical.