# What to do if you need packages from both conda and pip?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I've been developing my project with pip (django, drm etc). Now I need to use faiss, which only has unofficial package on pip (official - in conda). What should I do in this situation?
Can I combine them somehow? Or should I migrate to conda?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I combine them somehow?". Are you asking if you can have `conda` and `pip` installed packages in the same environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a non-conda environment, then you're limited to using `pip` only.  That is, `pip` does not know how to install conda packages.

But if you switch to using `conda`, then you can use either.  [The general recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418834/162094) is to install everything with `conda` if possible, but use `pip` when you have no other choice.

I recommend installing [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), then creating a new environment for all of your dependencies.  If necessary, add `pip`-only dependencies (if you have any).

```
conda create --name alex python=3.8 pip django requests bla-bla-bla
conda activate alex
pip install drm foo bar yada-yada
```

If you need uncommon or bleeding-edge packages, you might also consider obtaining your conda packages from the `conda-forge` channel, rather than the `defaults` channel.  [See here for instructions.](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge)

Comment: @AlexandrFarkas please see the edit above -- don't forget to `activate` the environment before calling `pip`!  (Thanks @merv.)