# How can I get pip to list the repositories it's using?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to get a codebase running on my machine, and pip isn't finding some of the dependencies. It seems to find them on another machine, so I'd like to see which repos pip is using on the two machines so I can compare.

How can I do this?

Comment: @JonClements Both of those just list installed packages, don't they?

Comment: Are you maybe after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667/is-there-a-way-to-list-pip-dependencies-requirements ?

Comment: @JonClements No? Maybe I'm not using the right terminology. When you tell pip to install a package with a certain name, it has to look that up online somewhere, to map the name onto an actual set of files to download. I want it to list all of the somewheres that it checks to get that information. Presumably in the form of a list of URLs or domains.

Comment: Ahhh... only a couple of places by default unless told otherwise by command line arguments - probably what you're after starts at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#finding-packages

Comment: have you tried **pip show (package_name)** .... it results in info where there are points called **Requires** and **Requires_by**... ?.. this may help out to straight out the dependencies...or if in linux try **which pip** to get the pip running source...might help ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Update for 21.1.2

(copied from @Bryan Roach's comment):

```
pip download --no-cache-dir --verbose "foo<0" 2>&1 |grep 'location(s) to search' -A5
```

#### Update for `pip>=20`

The repositories are now listed by default, no need to pass the `--verbose` arg:

```
$ pip download --no-cache-dir "foo<0" 2>&1 | grep Looking
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://my-index.local, http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

#### Original answer

The repositories where `pip` searches for packages are displayed when using `--verbose` flag: `pip install --verbose ...` or `pip download --verbose ...`. Specify some non-existent requirement so `pip` does not actually download/install anything. Example:

```
$ pip download --no-cache-dir --verbose "foo<0" 2>&1 | grep Looking
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://my-index.local, http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: My output was formatted a bit differently. Perhaps pip has been updated. This worked for my case: `pip download --no-cache-dir --verbose "foo<0" 2>&1 |grep 'location(s) to search' -A5`

Comment: @BryanRoach good catch - looks like the verbose output has changed. The command provided in the answer continues to work without the `--verbose` arg, though.

Comment: I have pip version 22.3.1 and it seems like verbose is additive now and it needs a double verbose to get the result described above: `pip download --no-cache-dir -v -v "foo<0"`

Answer (score 8):

Just run from a terminal :
`pip config list`