# configure pip for TLS/SSL, without rebuilding/re-installing

Tags: python-3.x, pip

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Is there a solution that does not involve reinstalling nor re-building the python executable? With conda installations or otherwise, you do not always know which source to use for rebuilding with SSL, which is what most other solutions suggest.

Comment: The `ssl` module [uses `_ssl`, which is built-in](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ssl.py), so I'm afraid it's not possible to incorporate that into Python without rebuilding it. As for which source to use, CPython's source is available on the official website. You may need to build some third-party libraries like OpenSSL before building Python

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Admittedly this makes one a bit nervous on a system where they have a full slew of packages already installed possibly (who knows) sensitive to a very specific python build.

Comment: You can dump all the information about the installed packages using pip (`pip freeze`, I believe). Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667/is-there-a-way-to-list-pip-dependencies-requirements). Then, once you have all the dependencies of your packages, identify the ones built into Python and build the interpreter according to that.