# How can I show a python package installed packages

Tags: python

If I install some python pacakges, like `opencv-python`, it will install the cv2 pacakge.

But before I look at opencv's document, how can I inspector the `opencv-python` pacakge, and find out what it installed.

Like `pip info opencv-python`, but it will not print the installed packages.

Update:

I find the pip installed place `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opencv_python-4.7.0.72.dist-info/top_level.txt` contains the top_level package(like installed packages). So I can write some script to parse this file, or python has builltin util to print this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers demonstrating [`pip show`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_show/) usage are fine if you just wanted to discover this information from the command-line interactively. If you want access to the top-level package names programmatically, however, pip is not much help because it [has no API](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program).

Since Python 3.10 the information is easily available using stdlib [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#mapping-import-to-distribution-packages):

```
>>> from importlib.metadata import packages_distributions
>>> dists = packages_distributions()
>>> [name for name, pkgs in dists.items() if "opencv-python" in pkgs]
['cv2']
```

If you want to know *all* the files owned by an installed package, not just the top-level import names, you can get that too [like this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-files):

```
from importlib.metadata import distribution
dist = distribution("opencv-python")
for file in dist.files:
    print(file)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip show <packagename>` will tell you where it's installed in the `Location` field ([docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_show/))

You could just list out the content, if that's all you're after, for example

```bash
find "$(pip show requests | grep Location | cut -d' ' -f2)/requests"
```

You can also use `pip freeze` to see what packages are installed

---

It's not possible to know in advance without looking at the code to see what a Python package will install because it needs to parse (normally run) `setup.py`
However, see [Is there a way to list pip dependencies/requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667/is-there-a-way-to-list-pip-dependencies-requirements) which suggests [`johnnydep`](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep) by [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) which seems up-to-date

Comment: Note: this only works because `requests` names the top-level package also `requests`.  But `opencv-python` from the question doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `pip show -f <PACKAGE>`—that is, `pip show` with the `-f` (or `--files`) flag, it will list the contents of the package. For example,

```
pip show -f opencv-python
```

or

```
pip show --files opencv-python
```

will list all the files installed by the package.