# pip, how to get dependencies BEFORE installing a application

Tags: pip

Is there any way in pip to get know dependencies of the applicaton before downloading it ?

on old version of pip i can do:

#### pip install --no-install raven

but not even this solution is not work !

Anybody know a solution ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing the dependencies of a package using pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460681/listing-the-dependencies-of-a-package-using-pip)

Comment: pip install --no-install --verbose do not work on new version of pip