# how to reduce size of python interpreter installation packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am trying to add Python 3 (with  minimal size) to an embedded Linux system (which is not present currently). I have cross compiled the Python 3 but the installation directory is around 95MB. I need to reduce this as much as possible to fit into the 64MB flash. I am trying to see if I can reduce it to around 20MB.

I would like to list the internal packages the Python programs are using. I got the list of external packages using the tools like `pipreqs` but I want to see the internal packages such as `os` so that I can remove the other packages and reduce the total size.

I can manually check for all imports and list it but I'd like to know if there is any alternative because there are a lot of files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing the dependencies of a package using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460681/listing-the-dependencies-of-a-package-using-pip)