# How do I figure out why pip installed a given package?

Tags: pip, dependency-management

Using `pip list`, I have just discovered that I have [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) installed in a container running in production. Since this library hasn't been updated [since 2013](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/#history) and has at least [one un-patched CVE](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/pull/256), I'd like to figure out what package I'm installing that is installing this as a dependency, because it's probably outdated and unmaintained as well. My `requirements.txt` has 60 dependencies (and `pycrypto` is not one of them), so I don't want to check them all manually.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to spin up a new Ubuntu install, install my dependencies one by one and see which one adds `pycrypto`?

Comment: have you tried `pip show`? if you go the route of having to check each dependency manually, you may not have to fully install each package. There are a number of SO questions about listing dependencies of a package without installing, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667/is-there-a-way-to-list-pip-dependencies-requirements , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232568/identifying-the-dependency-relationship-for-python-packages-installed-with-pip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+reverse+dependencies