# Kivy crashes in Android on launch

Tags: android, python, kivy, ws4py

When I start my Kivy app on my Android phone (Samsung GSIII) the splash screen appears then it crashes and returns to my previous screen. After trail and error I settled on the fact that my import of ws4py was causing the error.

I added ws4py to my buildozer.spec file under requirements `requirements = kivy,ws4py`, and it seems to download correctly while running `$>buildozer android debug`. Looking through the source code of ws4py and reading the docs, there are no imports other than modules in the standard lib so it doesn't seem to be a dependency issue (but maybe it is?).

The DDMS log is here:

```
05-02 09:17:29.677: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.687: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.687: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_image.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.697: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_image.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.697: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_image.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.697: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_ttf.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.697: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_ttf.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.697: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_ttf.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.697: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_mixer.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.707: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_mixer.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.707: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_mixer.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.707: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libpython2.7.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libpython2.7.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libpython2.7.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libapplication.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libapplication.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libapplication.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_main.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.727: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_main.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.737: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsdl_main.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.737: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.737: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.737: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.737: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.747: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.747: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.747: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsqlite3.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.757: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsqlite3.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.757: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.shufudesign.drmb-2/libsqlite3.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.757: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.757: D/dalvikvm(22120): Added shared lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.757: D/dalvikvm(22120): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x422833c8, skipping init
05-02 09:17:29.767: D/dalvikvm(22120): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so 0x422833c8
05-02 09:17:29.767: E/dalvikvm(22120): dlopen("/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
05-02 09:17:30.488: I/python(22120): ['/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/site-python']
05-02 09:17:30.488: I/python(22120): Android path ['/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/_applibs']
05-02 09:17:30.908: I/python(22120): [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-05-02_0.txt
05-02 09:17:31.990: I/python(22120):  /data/data/com.shufudesign.drmb/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:12: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
05-02 09:17:32.250: I/ActivityManager(610): Process com.shufudesign.drmb:python (pid 22120) (adj 0) has died.
05-02 09:17:32.250: W/ActivityManager(610): Force removing ActivityRecord{42ed13d0 u0 com.shufudesign.drmb/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}: app died, no saved state
```

I checked out a few questions on the kivy and python-for-android google groups of people who had the same question about the _imaging.so error. The response seemed to be that is not causing the issue. I stripped out everything in my app except drawing a circle (which works) and then adding the ws4py import (which breaks everything).

Is there something I am missing about adding third party libraries other than adding them to the spec file? Everything works fine when running in Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated because my app is dependent on web sockets to connect to my backend.

Comment: `RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom` -- this is what is killing your app. `pygame.cdrom` is a C extension module, and C extension modules can cause major problems for no apparent reason. ;) I notice that `ws4py` can build with `setuptools` or `distutils` - have you tried adding `setuptools` to your requirements?

Comment: I added setuptools and it is still giving me the same `import cdrom` error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same problem.  Adding openssl to the list of required modules fixed the issue (i.e. 'requirements = openssl, ws4py, kivy'  in buildozer.spec).

It helped to use snakefood to list the each of the modules loaded by a python script.  See [list python package dependencies without loading them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875232/list-python-package-dependencies-without-loading-them) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the INTERNET Android permission?

Also, ws4py has a lot of dependencies you might have to add. I can see problems especially with tornado, gevent, and cython. https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python/blob/master/requirements/py2kreqs.txt

Comment: Yes the internet permission is enabled. Also I am only using the base client of ws4py which doesn't include those dependencies and only requires the standard library.http://ws4py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sources/requirements/

Comment: I am using the built-in client "That client is solely based on the Python stdlib, it uses a thread to run the inner processing loop."

Comment: @brousch: ws4py doesn't have mandatory dependencies. However, some of its backends do require some of them indeed, only if you use them. But ws4py will not download them for you.