# Tool to output all modules & dependencies for Python project?

Tags: python, pycharm

Newbie question: Is there a tool that will scan a Python project & output a list of all dependencies & modules the project uses?

Comment: If you are using pip then you can just do `pip freeze` on the shell to print out pip packages installed. Otherwise look at the packages setup.py or requirements.txt

Comment: I'm using Pycharm.  Is there a simple way to get Pycharm to generate a setup.py or requirements.txt file?

Comment: Are you using your own code or are you looking at someone elses?

Comment: It's my own code.  There's 50+ scripts now in the project across several folders, and don't want to have to go through them 1 at at time.

Answer (score 2):

Generate dependency graphs from Python code

http://furius.ca/snakefood/

Example : [list python package dependencies without loading them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875232/list-python-package-dependencies-without-loading-them)

Comment: pip install snakewood v1.4 fails with syntax not compatible with python3.