# pip: upgrade package without upgrading particular dependency

Tags: python, django, pip

My question is very much similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861183/pip-upgrade-package-without-upgrading-dependencies) question. But It differs in a way that if i am installing some package i only want to disable upgrade for a particular dependency not for all dependencies. I know there is a flag `--no-deps` but it will exclude all dependency rather i just want to exclude one.

Here is a scenario:

- I have Django 1.4 installed
- I have [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta) installed

Here are `django-rosetta` dependencies in latest build:

```
install_requires=[
    'six >=1.2.0',
    'Django >= 1.3'
]
```

Now i want to upgrade rosetta `pip install -U django-rosetta`. But it tried to download and install `Django 1.5` because in rosetta dependency `Django >= 1.3` is required (and i don't want it to do this as Django 1.4 is already installed) I only want it to upgrade `six` package if there is any.

`--no-deps` flag will not work as it will exclude `six` package also. Also I am not using virtual environment. Any suggestions please?

Comment: In the example Pip tried to install `Django 1.5`, is this because `Django 1.4` was not installed using pip?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works and lets you be more precise:

```
pip install -U django-rosetta Django==1.4
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a requirement file `requirement.txt` containing:

```
Django==1.4
```

then

```
pip install -U django-rosetta -r requirement.txt
```

Comment: But if i follow this approach it would upgrade rest of the packages (apart from Django) which are in requirements.txt file.

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't understood your question, but you were asking for a way to prevent upgrading some specific package (Django) while upgrading everything else... what I'm saying is the requirement file can be use to block those specific packages to be upgraded and let pip upgrade others.

Comment: Just tested and it will work with `requirements.txt` file if you keep the version number also for every package.

Comment: @Guillaume a similar question, how to avoid installing some sub-dependancy, for example, I want to install `PyYAML` which depends on lxml, which will be automatically installed when installing PyYAML .. now, I want to avoid installing lxml and I will install it manually, either before or after .. how to do this?