# Pip install package with latest version, compatible with existing dependency

Tags: installation, pip, versioning

I have torch==1.8.0 installed.
Now want to install torch-tensorrt, but

```
pip install torch-tensorrt
```

results in upgrading torch:

```
torch                                2.0.1                
torch-tensorrt                       1.4.0
```

How do I can install the latest version of torch-tensorrt, compatible with installed torch 1.8.0?

Answer (score 0):

The [--upgrade-strategy only-if-needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861183/upgrade-package-without-upgrading-dependencies-using-pip) parameter in the form `pip install torch-tensorrt --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed` will only upgrade torch if the latest torch-tensorrt is incompatible with the current version.

If you want the latest torch-tensorrt that is compatible with torch 1.8, try:

- creating a requirements text file like

```
torch==1.8.0
torch-tensortt
```

- running `pip install -r _file name_`